# Equations of motion in matrix form and energy consumption

Tags: control-engineering, motors, energy, energy-efficiency, optimal-control

I am working on Lagrangian derived high-dimensional motion equations for a robot in matrix form. The structure of such an equation is known:

$M(q)\ddot{q}+C(q,\dot{q})\dot{q}+G(q)=0$

In here, $M(q)$, $C(q,\dot{q})$ are matrices, and  $G(q)$ are vector.

**Remark:** I mean they are matrices, vectors, etc., i.e. is it possible to somehow use their traces, determinant, norm and other to use for the study of energy consumption?

Are there any properties of $M(q)$, $C(q,\dot{q})$, $G(q)$ related to the power consumption of the robot and is it possible to optimize power consumption by operating with these very properties?

Comment: My suggestion is that you start from a two dimensional system (the 2dof system is a system that is easy to physically interpret). Then investigate the methods that work for "energy consumption"  (you are using it very vaguely), and then try to extrapolate at higher dimensions.

Comment: @NMech Yes, I agree. I need to start with something simple. And "vague", because I need to use a robot model to optimize energy properties and, as it seems to me, they should be embedded in the matrices of the equation of motion, but the criteria and cost functions are unknown to me. Therefore, it seems to me that it is quite an urgent task to establish the relationship between them.

Comment: Could you provide a description what is the physical interpretation of G?

Comment: @NMech If we divide the Lagrangian into kinetic and potential energies, then the composition of $G(q)$ will include all the components containing the derivative of the potential and kinetic energy with respect to the angular generalized coordinates (directly potential energies + kinetic energies with a moment of inertia depending on the angular generalized coordinates).

Comment: IMHO this is very specific to robotics (and the abstract way you are presenting your question is not helpful either), you could try the Robotics SE, where there is a higher probability you will have someone acquainted with your particular problem.

Comment: @NMech Yes, there I also asked a question, but that forum is not very active, like the others, and the answers are much less often given. We'll see. https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/22427/equations-of-motion-in-matrix-form-and-energy-consumption

Comment: You can't do much with the very general equation in your OP unless you have some context of what you are modelling. For example, on the face of it  $M(q)\ddot q$ says the inertia of the system depends on its position. Really? Do you mean the robot is picking up mass, moving it, and dropping it, or what? Or is inertia really constant and this is just "over-pedantic mathematical notation"?

Comment: @alephzero yes, we are talking about real physical cases when the moment of inertia is variable